# Simple html dom get value from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, simple-html-dom

Is it possible to get javascript var by using Simple html dom or are there other options?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.80991, 1.98722);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };


include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('url');
```

I want the lat and lng when i parse the url by Simple Html Dom. Is that possible?

Comment: can you pls elaborate on what exactly you want?

Comment: I want the value 11.80991 and 1.98722 filtered out of the html. Do i need simple html dom or is there an other way?

Comment: well, you'll need Simple Html DOM to retrieve the script from the page source code, then to extract the wanted values, you'll need regex for example... Tell us what is the source: is it a link? if not just post the full js script so ppl can work on it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. But maybe it's this:

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.80991, 1.98722);
    var lat = latlng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = "Latitude: " + lat;
    var lang = latlng.lng();
    document.getElementById('lang').innerHTML = "Longitude: " + lang;

    //Both:
    document.getElementById('both').innerHTML = "Lat/Long: " + latlng;
}
window.onload = initialize();
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grevling/7JaSG/2/)